# Registering sqlalchemy extension with current application using init_app()

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run an existing app in a new environment. The app ran fine in a previous environment, but when I run it locally it refuses to connect with my DB.

```
AssertionError: The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current application.  Please make sure to call init_app() first.
```

Where I'm confused is that this exact code worked in a previous environment. It's asking me to call init_app() but, from my understanding, that's only if there are multiple apps, which there aren't.

In debugging mode, the app does recognize the object i.e.

```
>>> type(Candidate)
<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta'>
```

I am unclear how and where to incorporate app_init() into my code. I have tried...

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)
```

but this didn't have any impact.

Folder structure...

```
app
- static folder
- templates folder
- _init_.py
- config.py
- views.py
- run.py
- Procfile
```

Comment: What are the previous and current environments? What does your folder structure look like? Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: In theory, the previous and current environments should be the same since I pip installed my requirements.txt and am using a virtualenv. Folder structure is above

Answer (score 4):

You could try following code and structure in **init**.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask()
    db.init_app(app)

    from user_model import User
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

Comment: The db has been created. Would this not overwrite it?

Comment: The db would be overwritten. By doing like this, you could import db without conflict with app.

Comment: Ok, I cannot overwrite the DB

Comment: Emmm, db is a SQLAlchemy object not a real database.

Comment: Thx. adding db.init_app() where I initialize my app changes the error. Now it's not recognizing my DB tables - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table. I tried db.create_all() but that didn't help.

Comment: If you tried to read a new table without any operation before, the new table would not be created util creating a new object and adding it to the session. It's lazy property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was legacy code that was supposed to be removed. I was initializing an app twice by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating **init.py**, why don't you import db directly from models

The code below shows my **models.py** with table students

```
from flask import Flask,session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


#initialize this two objects below app and db parameters so that app.py will have the same db session.
#then in app.py add from models import db
#finally add db.init_app(app) at the bottom of app.py or  run.py

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Students(db.Model):
   id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50))
   email = db.Column(db.String(50))

def __repr__(self):
        return '<Student {}>'.format(self.email)
```

Then in your **app.py or run.py**

You will have to make an import for db

```
from models import db
```

Your **assertion error** for **sql-alchemy** can be mitigate by moving the two following line of code
immediately after this line of code towards the bottom

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

hence the code will become like below and your application will run without issue

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   #create table
   db.create_all()
   db.init_app(app)


# remember to turn app debug by setting it to false in production
   app.run(debug=True)
```